# Get python ellipsis (...) type without having to define it as `type(...)`

Tags: python, python-3.x, ellipsis

Is there a way to get python's `Ellipsis` type? I saw that doing `type(Ellipsis)` and `type(...)` returns `<class 'ellipsis'>`, but by writing `x = ellipsis()` it seems like if `ellipsis` is not a default-defined data type (`NameError: name 'ellipsis' is not defined`).
I thought `builtins` builtin module could provide the solution to my problem, but the following also raises error.

```
import builtins
_ellipsis = builtins.ellipsis    # AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'ellipsis'
```

What i actually need it, is for doing something like this:

```
from typing import Union

def f(x: Union[str, type(...)]):
    pass
```

Obviously the previous works, but i'd like to have a more fancier solution that just `type(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis):

> `Ellipsis`
>
> The same as the ellipsis literal “...”. Special value used mostly in conjunction with extended slicing syntax for user-defined container data types. `Ellipsis` is the sole instance of the [`types.EllipsisType` type](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/types.html#types.EllipsisType).

So, in Python 3.10 (!) you can use `types.EllipsisType` to represent this type.

Otherwise, you can define your own variable like this:

```
EllipsisType = type(...)
```

And then use it in type declarations

Comment: `EllipsisType` seems to be new in Python 3.10 - worth mentioning in your answer.

Comment: i have just also found this clever hack by guido van rossum himself https://github.com/python/typing/issues/684#issuecomment-548203158

Comment: maybe `EllipsisType = type(builtins.Ellipsis)` is safer?

Comment: @Giuppox, what's the difference? `builtins.Ellipsis` and `...` are literally the same, aren't they? `...` is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: yeah, but what if the variable `Ellipsis` has been overwritten? `builtins.Ellipsis` would solve any problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Giuppox, `EllipsisType = type(...)` is safer because you can't overwrite the meaning of `...` since it's hard-coded into the interpreter. Also, you can easily say `builtins.Ellipsis = Ellipsis = 5` and now `type(builtins.Ellipsis) is int`. Anyway, you can use any version you like, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For now, what you are doing is the only way to get at it.

In [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#types), it will be available in the [types](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html#types.EllipsisType) module.

3.10 also added `NoneType` here, and `NotImplementedType`.